# Row count performance impact when loading paged data, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently optimizing our web application and I'm not sure about how to go from here: there is a big SQL database that contains a large archive table with several million entries. These rows need to be shown in our visualization as fast as possible (filtered by one or two fields and a timestamp and delivered to the JS part in the client via Ajax). I've created useful indexes in the DB and I also eliminated the need for cross-references via navigation properties in my archive entities, so that I can read data solely from one table and do the rest in the frontend, which boosted performance a lot.

While analyzing the different bottlenecks, I found a problem: I don't request *all* matching data in the frontend (nobody watches at 10000 rows at once) but use a paging mechanism done with skip() and take() on the server side. This also works nicely and fast, but in order to get the total amount of matching rows, I have to do a count somewhere. And this count() is really expensive: a full request cycle from the frontend with some filters usually takes around 10 to 30 milliseconds, but when I add a count to my query, this goes up to around 450 ms.

Now I wonder how to go on: should I just ignore the delay and just live with it? Or is there a good way to do pagination without knowing the total number of elements? I mean, somehow the frontend needs to know the number of rows, because it needs to calculate the number of pages and enable/disable a "next page" button etc.

Is there a good way to resolve this issue?

Update: here's my code with some comments:

```
var query = from x in db.ValueArchive select x;

// Filter by DatapointIds, if there are any
if (request.DatapointIds.Count>0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => request.DatapointIds.Contains((int)x.DataPointId));
}

// Filter by StationIds, if there are any
if (request.StationIds.Count > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => request.StationIds.Contains((int)x.StationId));
}

// Get number of matching rows after filtering
// This is the bottleneck!
response.numFound = query.Count();

// Paging
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Skip(request.Start == 0 ? 0 : request.Start-1).Take(request.Length);

// Add paging info to response
response.Start = request.Start;
response.Length = request.Length;

// Convert datetimes to ISO8601
response.Rows = query.Select(x => new { d = x.DataPointId, s = x.StationId, t = x.DateValue.Value, v = x.Value })
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new { d = x.d, s = x.s, t = x.t.ToString("o"), v = x.v }).ToList<Object>();
```

Comment: Any code maybe?

Comment: You could try partitioning. I cannot give you any specific ideas about it without the code though.

Comment: Also, columnstore indexes can do wonders to performance of aggregation queries

Comment: what _paging mechanism_ do you use? (Custom or..)

Comment: Don't calculate count multiple times, do it once only.

Comment: Online relational databases are not always best for visualization queries and search. You could try indexing the data in something like Lucene, for example, in which case getting counts is quite fast even for billions of records. What kind of data are you searching? Can you tell us more or show some of your paging code? Paging doesn't have to be purely based on user clicking buttons, can just keep asking server for next page and stop when no more pages/records (like ajax lazy loading).

Comment: I added some code with the relevant part that fetches the data. I think there are two ways: either increase the row count speed after filtering (which I don't think is possible), or find a stable solution *without* doing a row count at all. I start liking the latter...

Answer (score 2):

To perform `SELECT COUNT(*)` , SQL Server will use the narrowest non-clustered index to count all rows. So, if table doesn't have any non-clustered indexes, it will have to scan the whole table.
If you have one, then you can use this (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql)):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(s.id) [YourTable], s.rowcnt [Row_Count]
FROM sys.sysindexes s WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE s.indid in (0,1)
ORDER BY s.rowcnt desc
```

As a workaround you can use the technique that Microsoft uses to quickly display the number of rows when you right click on the table and select properties.

```
select sum (spart.rows)
from sys.partitions spart
where spart.object_id = object_id(’YourTable’)
and spart.index_id < 2
```

You can use ADO to execute this (or make sql function) code and get your result (instead of running `count()` method on your entity).

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice trick that I already use to get the *total* row count of that table (and it is 50x faster than count). Unfortunately, I can't use that to get the number of rows after filtering.

Comment: @Robert So what if you make SQL string from your `query` by calling `query.ToString()`, then wrap this around to that string and execute? I'm not quite sure yet if thats possible, but I will test and let you know.

Comment: SeM, the problem is that I don't need the row count for a whole table, I need a row count for the rows that I get after applying a *where()* to my query. The above trick does not allow for that, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I get it, but if you call `query.ToString()`, **after** your `where()`, you will get the generated SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a good way to do pagination without knowing the total
>   number of elements?

Yes, it is possible
You dont have to call count() to get total number of items to do paging.
items COUNT is not mandatory.

At a point of time, pageIndex = n, If count of returned items < pageSize ==> n is the last page

- click back ==> get items for pageIndex = n-1.
- click next ==> get items for pageIndex = n+1.

=> This way make you have to browse pages step by step (the most popular behavior, i thinks)

In the case there is someone click last => Only in this case you have to get items count. Lets see how you googling. Have you ever browsed the last page?

Comment: You're right, this is probably the best way to go, from a user's perspective. And that's what counts in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The COUNT(*) OVER () will give you the total count regardless of paging at the same query without extra query:

```
select 
    row_number() OVER (order by  col1,col2 ) rowNumber,
    1 Page,
    (CEILING(CasT(COUNT(*) OVER () as float)/30)) Pages,
    COUNT(*) OVER () Rows, 

    col1,col2

from mytable mainlist 
where   myfilters=myfiltervalue
order by rowNumber 
OFFset (1-1)*30 rows 
FETCH NEXT 30 rows only ;
```